# Rails 4.1 with ActiveJob gem - uninitialized constant ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I have followed the [getting started with active job](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/getting-started-with-active-job/) article by EngineYard. The article states:

> You'll need Rails 4.2.0beta1 or greater if you want to Active Job available by default (in older versions of Rails, you can require it as a gem)

I am trying to use ActiveJob in my Rails 4.1 project. I added ActiveJob to my gemfile `gem 'activejob'`. As per the article, I have:

```
#config/initializers/active_job.rb
ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :resque
```

However, when I run `rails server` I get the following error:

`config/initializers/active_job.rb:1:in`': uninitialized constant ActiveJob (NameError)`

**EDIT** - Fixed typo "gem active job"

**UPDATE 1**

Following solydest's suggestion below, adding `require 'active_job'` to application.rb allows me to no longer get the `uninitialized constant ActiveJob` error but instead I receive the error `undefined method perform_later'` when I try to call my job. I am following the [edge rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) and enqueue my job with code similar to:

```
MyJob.perform_later(record)
```

The beginning of my job class:

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :images
  def perform(id)
```

Comment: You can't have spaces in your gem names. It's `gem 'activejob'`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my question, I actually have the correct spelling as you listed in my gemfile. I have updated the question.

Comment: Ok, what's the output of `bundle show activejob`?

Comment: /Users/marklar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4.1_app/gems/activejob-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that the gem version of ActiveJob for rails 4.1 is 0 which is different from the version in Rails 4.2.

If you're using the v0 of ActiveJob, the syntax should be :

```
MyJob.enqueue(record)
```

or

```
MyJob.enqueue(record, options)
```

You will find a lot of interesting things about ActiveJob with Rails 4.1 in this article :
http://kinopyo.com/blog/use-activejob-in-rails-4-1/

Comment: Fantastic article. I think it's worth mentioning that the article uses `require 'active_job'` similar to solydest's answer. I've mentioned this just in case the link to the article dies.

Answer (score 10):

I added `require 'active_job'` to config/application.rb just below all the other require directives and that solved the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I add `require 'active_job'` then I no longer get ` uninitialized constant` but instead receive the error `undefined method `perform_later'`. I will update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this gem if you want to use Active Job on Rails 4.0 or 4.1:

https://github.com/ankane/activejob_backport

But this gem did not pull Action Mailer in, you need to stick with `deliver`, see https://github.com/ankane/activejob_backport/issues/1.